# Can I use IPsec as a substitute for TLS and SSL?

Tags: encryption, ipsec

I know that SSL and TLS are almost just the same and are used as encryption protocols for encrypting the data that is travelling over the internet. But TLS and SSL provide encryption support for data related to some protocols only (FTP, HTTP etc) and not all.

But on the other hand we have IPsec that also encrypts the data totally. So I am wondering that can I solely use IPsec for my communication and don't use SSL and TLS as IPsec will totally encrypt the packet while TLS and SSL encrypts just a part of the packet and that too some specific packets.

Is this scenario possible and its it secure ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is better for server-to-server-communication: IPSec or TLS?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42990/which-is-better-for-server-to-server-communication-ipsec-or-tls). See also [Are there any reasons for using SSL over IPSec?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63330/are-there-any-reasons-for-using-ssl-over-ipsec) which also explains differences and use cases.

Comment: IMHO, whether to decide to use TLS or VPN essentially boils down to whether you see yourself as an application developer writing a set of networked services or a network administrator deploying a set of applications. Application developers generally choose TLS as TLS is easier to integrate with the application; while network administrator generally choose IPSec as they don't need to modify the application. This isn't an absolute though, it's possible to add TLS without modifying application (e.g. socat) and it's possible to built in IPSec into an application.

Comment: Security wise they aren't that different.